# Accesing IOS8 built in camera editing features

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift, camera

Is there a way/API to access built in IOS8 crop and rotate feature, i am creating an app in which i want to store an image after the user crops a particular selection of it. Can i use built-in crop/rotate IOS8 feature in my application using any obj-c/swift API..

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring using code to corp and rotate then use CGContext API:

CGImageCreateWithImageInRect for corp.

CGAffineTransformRotate for rotate.